# AX2012 - Change Visual Studio project path

Tags: visual-studio, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am having trouble opening/compiling a visual studio project in AX2012. Directly it complains about a file that does not exist. However, the underlying problem seems to be that the path + filename combination is too long.

It currently places the source code in: c:\users\%userprofile%\appdata\local\temp\2\Dynamics AX\Visual Studio\C Sharp projects... (From the top of my head). I have noticed if I manually attempt to copy the VS project to this folder in Windows Explorer I get an error message about the filename that is too long as well. Copying it to a folder higher up in the structure solves this. However, the moment I compile it in Ax (Through the AOT) it tries to find the above mentioned folder again.

Can this be changed somewhere?

I have tried changing the TEMP and TMP environment variables. I cannot imagine that this would be setup in VS, as the files get created by AX, and are then opened in VS.

Any advice? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this with a work-around. I compiled the VS project through the AOT on a different machine, then copied the DLL and config file to the VSAssemblies folder on the AOS (./bin/VSAssemblies). In my case there were no client code. Started the AOS and the changes became effective

EDIT: Recently had contact with MS support team, and they agreed that this workaround is also what they would give as advice